# Can you use a for loop for a selling process?

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to make a selling process in Roblox and  wanted to make a selling & stealing system. Simply put, when you steal the item, it goes into a folder. Then when you sell, I have a for loop and the way I want to process to go is however many items are in the folder, that is how much money you get.
script:

```
local Items = game.Workspace["BackpackCurrency's"]:GetChildren()

game.Workspace["Seller man"].UpperTorso.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function()
    for i, v in pairs(Items) do
        game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Credits.Value = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Credits.Value + tonumber(i)
    end
end)
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what is wrong. Taking a guess, are the changes to the values not permanent?

Comment: it doesnt work at all

Comment: Does the ProximityPrompt event fire? What are the contents of the Items array?

Comment: Where is this LocalScript located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local Items = game.Workspace["BackpackCurrency's"]

game.Workspace["Seller man"].UpperTorso.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    player.leaderstats.Credits.Value += #(Items:GetChildren())
    Items:ClearAllChildren()
end)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the newly working script. I am currently going over this to notice how your changes have effected my script. thank you.